# iphone:Error while fetching data from array of one view to another view

Tags: iphone

In my apps i have two simple view. in first view i show only static values through array into table now by clicking on the row the view ll change an the value of that row will show in the second view. In my apps values are stored correctly but when i code in second view to display that value it does not show any error but value is not display..My code is below:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)Animated{

   txtName.text=data;

   }
```

data is NSString in that i stored the values of an array.

Comment: Upload your detail code. How the Data is coming in `data` ? How are you assigning value to that `data` ?

Comment: provide more details. What `data` referenced to?

Comment: Please do provide sufficient details while you post question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work...

```
    txtName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data description]];
```